# Mi programa de VB trae el registro con todo y espacios en blanco, pero en la web lo muestra sin el espacio que debería tener

Tags: html, json, vb.net

En Productos me llama ese nombre, pero sin espacio

[image: En Productos me llama ese nombre, pero sin espacio]

pero en mi base de datos esta así

```
|INCA KOLA 3000 ML  AREQUIPA | TRUJILLO | CUSCO|
```

, o sea, con 2 espacios entre `ML` y `AREQUIPA`. Lo que necesito es que en mi WEB se muestre tal y como está en mi base de datos.

Comment: Parece que aca tambien los esta juntando

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es aca??? como podemos saber si hay 1 solo espacio o dos???

Comment: Y cómo es el código que pinta esos datos en la pizarra? Puedes [edit] y mostrarnos

Comment: En web por lo general los espacios múltiples uno a continuación de otro son ignorados y se muestra solo uno. Si quieres mantener múltiples espacios visibles tienes varias opciones... convertir los espacios a `&nbsp;` (que se muestra como espacio) o usar `<pre>Tu texto aquí</pre>` puesto que <pre> mantiene el formato original al 100%, manteniendo múltiples espacios, tabuladores e incluso los saltos de línea.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.